# Why do I get errors when I add items to a JList?

Tags: java

```
JList list;  
list=new JList();  
list.add("string");
```

I can't run the program (I get an error). The error says:

```
 The method add(Component) in the type `Container` is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

I tried using `JList<String>` but it still doesn't work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add **data** to a `JList` directly.

Use a `ListModel` instead.

```
    DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    list.setModel(listModel );

    // Add elements to the Model
    listModel.addElement("hello");
```

Comment: What is a list model? I tried to understand it from various google searches but I don't get it. It has to do with Model-View-Control thing, right?

Answer (score 1):

Make an array to add the items to:

```
arraylist string = new arraylist [size that you want];
arraylist.add ( what u want to add in here);
```